# Como alinhar texto no centro de um card?

Tags: ionic

Estou procurando uma maneira de alinhar o texto do componente card no ionic. Como fazer isso ?

```
<div class="card">
          <div class="item item-image">
            <img ng-src={{imagem}} id="smallimage">
          </div>
          <div class="item item-divider">
            {{nome}}
          </div>                         
      </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Achei essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25861158/how-can-i-align-button-in-center-or-right-using-ionic-framework) aqui no SO-inglês.
Basta adicionar `text-center` na sua div.

Veja o [exemplo](http://codepen.io/douglask/pen/zxXvYY) de uma das resposta aplicado ao botão `search`.

Comment: obrigado @Marconi eu estava tentando `item-text-center` mas agora funcionou blzinha.

Comment: @FernandoPaiva tranquilo, que bom que pude ajudar :).